# Link ICC C++11/C++14 code with link.exe of Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, icc

Can you compile a C++11/14 program using the most recent ICC (2015) together with the linker of MSVC2012?

Or will ICC disable C++11 features that the corresponding compiler of MSVC2012 would not have supported, if you enable binary compatibility for MSVC2012?

The background is that if you have purchased ICC, you still need the Microsoft build tools (at least the linker), which are not free to use for companies above a certain size. But if you have a license for MSVC2012, you could reuse its linker. The question is, will this combination work with most recent C++11/14 features supported by ICC?

Comment: Just a correction. As of now, the most recent version of Intel Compiler is [16.0 Update 1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compiler-and-composer-update-version-numbers-to-compiler-version-number-mapping) (Included in Parallel Studio XE 2016). You might also be interested in that Microsoft plans to ship [Standalone Visual C++ Build Tools 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments.aspx) along with Update 1 to Visual Studio (not sure though about licensing).

Comment: Are you asking about [`/Qvc`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/582152) and  [`/Qms`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/582151) options?

Comment: @drop yes i am talking about those options

Comment: @drop the 2016 intel release is not compatible with the standalone tools yet

Comment: I've just tried `/Qvc12` and it does not disable for example `constexpr` (which is not supported by VS2013). But there is another problem: switching to `/Qvc11` breaks everything because of the Standard library. AFAIK, `icc` on Windows uses the best Microsoft standard library it can find. So even if Intel would have perfect C++11/C++14 language features set, with library from VC11 you wouldn't gain much of it. Speaking about linker solely, there is one in MSYS binutils port (used by MinGW for example). Not sure it can really make any difference and how painful and reliable it can be.

Comment: @Drop hm, I see. Thanks for your research.

Comment: @Drop hm that seems to mean that to be able to use the intel compiler, you also have to buy the MSVC compiler/studio.

Comment: I believe your company can still use Express Editions of Visual Studio 2015 (with no GUI integration from Intel). And Community edition might be available for you too. [Quote](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350): `In non-enterprise organizations up to 5 users can use Visual Studio Community. In
enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or > $1M in annual revenue) no use is permitted for
employees as well as contractors beyond the open source, academic research and classroom learning environment
scenarios described above.`